# hide form items with dynamic class name in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, selection

I am trying to use class name to hide a class, for example:

```
$(".Half_Vent").hide();
```

it works fine. But I want to use drop down selection option value to dynamically replace the `.Half_Vent`, and here is the syntax I use:

```
$("\"."+ $("#details").val()+"\"").hide();
```

The value solved as `.Half_Vent` is good, but whole jQuery does not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Remove \", i.e.:

```
$("."+ $("#details").val()).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
 $("#cambio").on('change', function(){
  $("."+$(this).val()).hide();
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cambio">
  <option value="select">Select</option>
  <option value="muestra">Muestra</option>
  <option value="muestrab">Muestra B</option>
  <option value="muestrac">Muestra C</option>
</select>
<div class="muestra">Muestra 1</div>
<div class="muestrab">Muestra 2</div>
<div class="muestrac">Muestra 3</div>
```

Try this:

```
<select id="cambio">
   <option value="select">Select</option>
   <option value="muestra">Muestra</option>
   <option value="muestrab">Muestra B</option>`
   <option value="muestrac">Muestra C</option>
</select>
<div class="muestra">Muestra 1 </div>
<div class="muestrab">Muestra 2 </div>
<div class="muestrac">Muestra 3 </div>

$(function(){
   $("#cambio").on('change', function(){
       $("."+$(this).val()).hide();
   })
})
```

That way you control change

Comment: Carlos Quintero: Excellent! Thank you very much!